# Classification with cut() provides na

Tags: r, dplyr, classification

I would like to add class which from LimAm to LimAv with that dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(Position = c(1925.12260901036, 2463.70794121719, 
1282.23738714798), ID = c(11, 12, 24), LimAm = c(39943.8043856595, 
40482.3897178663, 39300.9191637971), LimAv = c(40443.8043856595, 
40982.3897178663, 39800.9191637971)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

However, when I apply the `cut()` function (which worked previously before updating the dataset), I obtain NA values instead of class type (LimAm;LimAv]:

```
df %>% mutate(class=cut(Position,c(LimAm, LimAv),include.lowest = FALSE))
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Position    ID  LimAm  LimAv class
     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>
1    1925.    11 39944. 40444. NA   
2    2464.    12 40482. 40982. NA   
3    1282.    24 39301. 39801. NA
```

I would like to understand why this code which was previously working perfectly, is not functional now I have added a new row...

Comment: The issue is that no value of ´Position` fits into the breaks you have specified, i.e. all values are smaller than the lower boundary of the first break which is `39301`. Hence all values are assigned `NA`.

Comment: Yes you are right, I identify a problem with one of the shapefile I use to obtain LimAv and LimAm. I corrected it and everything is going well. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are cutting the `Position` variable (values between 1280 and 2460) using cutpoints that take values between 39300 and 40980. Since none of the values are between any of the cutpoints they all get returned as `NA`.

If you change your cutpoints you'll get something else back.

```
> with(df, cut(Position, c(LimAm, LimAv)*0.0485))
[1] (1906,1930] <NA>        <NA>       
Levels: (1906,1930] (1930,1937] (1937,1962] (1962,1963] (1963,1988]
```

(note that there's still two values that are not in the range 1906-1988)

Comment: Thank you, It is therefore a correct answer (Position didn't matched with LimAm and LimAv). However, the problem came from something upstream (a file used to obtain LimAm and LimAv values). I corrected it